# Fastapi API calls is blocking multiple requests, due to this parallel calls to API is not working

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, rest, fastapi

I have built an API which requires heavy parallel CPU computation, I deployed onto development environment.

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/gunicorn \
    -b 0.0.0.0:8001 \
    -w 1 \
    -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app \
    --timeout 1200 \
    --chdir /app \
    --log-level 'info' \
    --error-logfile '-'\
    --access-logfile '-'
```

All is working good and the API is working fine.

I have two desktops, At the same time from different machines I made a request to the deployed API parallelly. But what happened is that, only one request was processed and returned and then after the completion of first request second request started to process and returned.

Because of this, second desktop took around 1 minutes to fetch results, whereas first desktop took around 20-25 seconds.

What could be the reason behind this? Does anyone have come across such type of behavior?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Joshua Not yet. I thought it could be due to my code being not optimized or too cpu exptensive. So, I optimized but still face the issue.